# Variables in HandlebarsJS

Tags: handlebars.js

Currently have two problems with HandlebarsJS.

Firstly, how can I create a variable for future use based on the results of a helper?
Secondly, how can I use the results within an if?

This is what I'm aiming for an failing. Could someone help me think the Handlebars way please?

```
<div class="basket">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="fewer" class="{{#if getQuantity this ../../../basket == 0}}hide{{/if}}">-</button>    
    <div class="quantity" class="{{#if getQuantity this ../../../basket == 0}}hide{{/if}}">{{ getQuantity this ../../../basket }} x</div>
    <button class="more">{{ currency this.pricePerUnit }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to create a helper but item is just a [Function] at this point...

```
hbs.registerHelper('if_zero', function(item, block) {
  if(item === 0) {
    return block(this);
  }
});
```

Any help would be great.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

*Handlebars way* here is not in trying to create helpers like *if_anything* but prepare your template before rendering. In your case you need new variable like **isBasketEmpty** and bring out that logic from template.